# jOOQ ignores column name casing when generation code from Postgresql table

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

I'm using jOOQ 3.10.1 with Postgres JDBC driver 42.1.4 and trying to generate code for following table:

```
create table "SampleTable"(
    "ID" serial primary key,
    "AnotherField" integer
);
```

jOOQ generates following code:

```
public interface ISampletable extends Serializable {
    public Integer getId();
    public Integer getAnotherfield();
//...
```

How can i configure jOOQ to generate case-sensitive code?

Comment: Another good example why quoted identifiers should be avoided

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: One use-case for this approach is if a schema needs to be kept compatible across vendors, e.g. SQL Server (if SQL Server is the "main" target database). Historically, things are named in `PascalCase`, there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, jOOQ's code generator follows Java's code style:

- classes are generated in `PascalCase`
- members and methods are generated in `camelCase`
- identifiers are generated in `UPPER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORE`

But you can override this behaviour easily using a generator strategy. There are two flavours:

- Programmatic (more powerful, a bit more effort to set up): https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-generatorstrategy
- Configurative (less powerful, quite easy to set up): https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-matcherstrategy

In your case, the configurative approach might do, or you can simply use the built-in `org.jooq.codegen.KeepNamesGeneratorStrategy`.